# How is a rollback with South supposed to work?

Tags: database, django, rollback, django-south

Color me confused. Let's assume we've got a Django project with South migrations. Currently, production project version is `A`, version in development `B`. Now let's suppose version `B` is installed into production:

1. Install new code
2. Run `./manage.py syncdb && ./manage.py migrate`
3. Restart web-server and be happy.

Next assumption: version `B` doesn't work at all. It did in development, but doesn't in production, so it has to be rolled back. And this is where I must be missing something. I see two possibilities:

1. Old code in reinstalled. Now, a South back-migration would be appropriate, however, this is not possible, since the old code doesn't contain all the newest migrations needed to go back.
2. We first roll-back database changes and then reinstall the old code. However, how do we know which migration is the latest for version `A`? Since one project could easily count a couple dozen apps, you'd need to figure out for each of them which migration stand belongs to the old version, then migrate each app separately and then rollback the code and hope for the best.

In both cases, I'm missing crucial information, either migration code in the first case or "migration `<->` version" relationship in the second. What am I missing here?

**PS**: Yes, I know I can restore the database from backup, this is what I actually do. I want to know how this whole database migration theory fits with rollbacks.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I presume you are working with version control?? That is pretty much crucial at this point to determine what makes up 'A' and 'B'. If we're hand-waving/guessing that this amorpheous blob of code we are referencing is 'A', and this other vaguely defined thing we all label as 'B' - it isn't going to work.

If you are trying to reinstall 'A' in the place of 'B' you have two options:
1) checkout and rebuild 'A' from scratch (sync and migrate)
2) roll 'B' back to 'A'.

1) Likely won't work because you can't afford to kill the data in DB to sync it from nothing
2) Involves migrations. First, you should find the migrations in 'B' and not in 'A'. In south all the migrations for each app are numbered (0001, 0002, 0003, etc). So let's say 'B' is at 050, and 'A' is at 0031. While you have 'B' checked out, run `python manage.py migrate appname 0031` That will undo all the DB changes you made for 'B'. Then in your version control system you checkout 'A' (whether 'A' is just a commit or a tag or a branch)

Unfortunately you can't rollback to 'A' and then say "unmigrate everything you don't have". That would be an easier solution - but then you'd need you migration system to know about your version control system, and that is a bit hairy.

Comment: Essentially, this is what I described as second possibility -- a lot of manual work and kind of defeats the whole backwards migration thing, since restoring the database from backup is just easier and probably faster :(

Comment: it would not be hard at all to write a script that gets the migration files you need, and runs them. restoring from backup seems much much slower - especially as your DB grows.

Comment: A simpler solution might be to have South be able to dump out a text file listing where the database is right now, in the manner of `pip freeze`. It could perhaps just include all the `./manage migrate myapp xxxx` commands. You'd dump and save the output when you're working on a new branch, then run it when you want to rollback. You could name the file after the commit, I guess. For now one could write a script to parse the output of `./manage migrate --list` and do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was an option in your case but couldn't you have run the backwards migration in production *before* you moved your code back to version 'A'?  This way your db gets back to whichever migration was there before you did your syncdb and then you change your code back to version A and you're right back to where you started.